# Salesforce Apache Pulsar integration

Tags: integration, developer-console, platform-event

I'm starting a project where we will be using Apache Pulsar as a messaging platform and going with an event driven integration pattern between Sales Cloud and and external systems (Finance, HR, etc).

I understand that there is also a Salesforce Event Platform available. Can anyone advise on whether I should use the Salesforce event platform in addition to Apache Pulsar or simply connect to Apache Pulsar as a subscriber /publisher ? Would be great if someone can give a high level conceptual explanation of the big pieces to consider here.

Comment: We'd need to know more about the Use Case to advise you on anything...

Comment: Hi @Robs, basically,  I would need to be publishing customer and order info to an ERP system every time an order is created in Salesforce. Also, I would need to subscribe to a product database to get all the latest product information which could be associated to orders. In all cases, the integration pattern will be event driven and the enterprise architecture team has chosen Apache Pulsar as the messaging platform.  Hope that helps.

Comment: One thing to be mindful of with Platform Events or Change Data Capture: there's no guaranteed delivery of messages when they're published. Your implementation should account for messages not being delivered, if delivery of every message is critical to your integration.

Comment: Take a look at [Integration Patterns](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.integration_patterns_and_practices.meta/integration_patterns_and_practices/integ_pat_intro_overview.htm).

Comment: thanks @identigral, are there built in connectors I can use such as from this list :https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/io-connectors/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd highly recommend you read:

- [Platform Events Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_intro.htm)

Specifically:

- [Subscribe to Platform Event Notifications with CometD](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_subscribe_cometd.htm)

As this is the way to subscribe to `Platform Event` via the API:

```
/v50.0/sobjects/Event_Name__e
```